# How do I build a debian package containing gettext .mo-files

Tags: gettext, dpkg-buildpackage

I want to create a .deb-package with a translation file split.mo, but I don't know how to get this into the .deb-file.

I have built an automake/autoconf utility named split. Everything is okay with that.
Now I want to build a .deb file.
I included the .mo-file in debian/conffiles: /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/split.mo
But when I run dpkg-buildpackage, I get an error saying the above .mo-file is not in that package.